# Get Firebase Auto-ID column in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter, firebase

Reviewing one of my Firebase schemas I can see that I have a couple of columns, but the auto-generated ID column does not show up:

[image]

However, when clicking on "Manage Content" the ID column can be seen:

[image]

The problem I have is that in other collections I make a reference to this collection by this ID, however, it doesn't pop-up in FlutterFlow to filter on:

[image]

**Question**: Is it possible to get the Auto-ID column in FlutterFlow?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is unfortunately not possible.

You could solve this by adding a column CopyOfId to your scheme.

You could then write a Firebase Function that triggers when you create a new document (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.firestore.documentbuilder.md?authuser=0#firestoredocumentbuilderoncreate). You could make this function copy the contents of the ID column to your own CopyOfId, making it accessible in FlutterFlow.

A deeper question is maybe for what use case you want this behaviour: why would you need to filter on an autogenerated ID that you do not know the value of - and that you can't access - in FlutterFlow? If we know your use case, there is probably another way to achieve what you want to achieve.